# How to execute a multiple raw query using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2. I have a raw SQL statement that I like to execute.

Here is what I tried

```
DB::select( $sql );
```

However, this works for the first query. If I execute another query in the same run I get the following error

```
FatalErrorException in Connection.php line 323: Cannot access empty property
```

So if I execute this

```
DB::select( sql1 );
```

and then

```
DB::select( $sql2 );
```

How can I execute multiple queries in the same run time.

I will get an error. Do I need to reinitialize the DB class before I call the second query? if so how would I reset it?

**UPDATED**

```
dd( $sql  );
```

I get the following

```
 "  SELECT TOP 1 '1' FROM survey_answer_defined INNER JOIN survey_answer_groups ON survey_answer_groups.id = survey_answer_defined.group_id WHERE survey_answer_groups.interview_id = '243' AND survey_answer_groups.control_id IN(300) AND 'E' IN('A','B','D','E')"
```

If I try the following instead

```
DB::select(DB::unprepared($sql))
```

I get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[HY090]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (SQL: )
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you write your sql queries inside a variable and pass it like the following:

```
\DB::unprepared( $mySQLQuery ); //mySQLQuery is complete query you want to be executed as you would do inside the DBMS..
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I am trying to select a data set. DB::raw or DB:unprepared will execute the query and will return true/false not a dataset. Additionally per my notes in the question. `DB::select(DB::unprepared($sql))` will give me an error `SQLSTATE[HY090]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (SQL: )`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I think selecting '1' does not work with Laravel.

Here is wha I did for the query to work

I changed

```
SELECT TOP 1 '1' 
FROM survey_answer_defined INNER JOIN survey_answer_groups ON survey_answer_groups.id = survey_answer_defined.group_id WHERE survey_answer_groups.interview_id = '243' AND survey_answer_groups.control_id IN(300) AND 'E' IN('A','B','D','E')
```

to

```
SELECT TOP 1 survey_answer_defined.id 
FROM survey_answer_defined INNER JOIN survey_answer_groups ON survey_answer_groups.id = survey_answer_defined.group_id 
WHERE survey_answer_groups.interview_id = '243' AND survey_answer_groups.control_id IN(300) AND 'E' IN('A','B','D','E')"
```